# Saving and reloading special characters

Tags: ckeditor

Using version 4.3.2 of ckeditor.

Our users are looking to use the playing card characters (spade, club, heart, diamond) within the html.

I save the contents to a NVARCHAR(max) field in our database.

After entering the code into the window, then saving it, the system html encodes the character into the

&clubs;

BUT in a later version of the CKEDITOR (4.7.3) the editor is working correctly, and saving the data correctly.

Here is the issue.

Previous developers have created additional buttons, plug-ins and toolbars.  When i copy the ckeditor.js into the directory, the additional plugins, and toolbars are not being displayed.

Even just stepping up or down a incremental version of ckeditor the tool bars and buttons are not being shown.

It appears that the ckeditor.js is obfuscated(sp)

Does the ckeditor.js get compiled, or built using a tool or something similar?

please help with what i am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the version, and it appear to be working correctly.